# How to change category thumbnail size in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, thumbnails

With the following code I managed to display my featured categories title, description and thumbnail. When I uploaded the thumbnail, it was 500 * 500 in its dimensions. But when I visit the page I see the thumbnail being cropped as 150 * 150.

```
<?php
    $args_t = array(
        'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat',
        'include'      => array( 16, 15, 17 ),
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    );
    $thirds_categories = get_categories( $args_t );
    foreach ( $thirds_categories as $cat ) {
        if( $cat->category == 0 ) {
            $cat_class = mb_strtolower($cat->name);
            $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
            $cat_thumb_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
            $cat_thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $cat_thumb_id );
            $term_link = get_term_link( $cat, 'product_cat' );?> 

            <div class="categories_box">
                    <a href="<?php echo $term_link; ?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo $cat_thumb_url; ?>" alt="<?php echo $cat->name; ?>" />
                        <h4> <?php echo $cat->name; ?> </h4>
                        <p><?php echo $cat->description; ?> </p>
                        <button>View Products</button>
                    </a>    
            </div>
       <?php }                          
    } wp_reset_query();
?>
```

How can I change the size of my categorythumbnails?

It is my first time doing a WooCommerce site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `wp_get_attachment_image_src();` for getting different sizes of image. This will return you an array with URL, width, height and cropping mode of this image.
Have a try

```
$args_t = array(
        'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat',
        'include'      => array( 16, 15, 17 ),
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    );
    $thirds_categories = get_categories( $args_t );
    foreach ( $thirds_categories as $cat ) {
        if( $cat->category == 0 ) {
            $cat_class = mb_strtolower($cat->name);
            $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
            $cat_thumb_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
            $cat_thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $cat_thumb_id );
            $term_link = get_term_link( $cat, 'product_cat' );
            $thmb = wp_get_attachment_image_src($cat_thumb_id, 'medium');

            ?> 

            <div class="categories_box">
                    <a href="<?php echo $term_link; ?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo $thmb[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $cat->name; ?>" />
                        <h4> <?php echo $cat->name; ?> </h4>
                        <p><?php echo $cat->description; ?> </p>
                        <button>View Products</button>
                    </a>    
            </div>
       <?php }                          
    } wp_reset_query();
```

Let me know if you need any more assistance. Thanks

Comment: I just did that but now it does not print the image. When I inspect the page I see the image source as unknown.

Comment: Tryout to `print_r($thmb);` to see what's coming inside.

Comment: It prints the number 1.

Comment: so you saying that you create a category, add a thumbnail to it and shows with no problem?

Comment: Yes. This is printing url at zero position. Are you still getting any error?

Comment: Yes I still see the unknown in the image source

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154415/discussion-between-bilal-hussain-and-wosley-alarico).

Answer (score 1):

// You can pass "thumbnail", "medium", "large" and "full"

```
$cat_thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'full' );

echo $cat_thumb_url[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

just go to your `wp-admin` wordpress admin section and login, then select menu from sidebar as below

```
woocommerce -> settings -> products (tab) -> Display Option
```

check have `'Product images'` title where you can set image size. so when u add/upload any new product image woocommerce auto crop image at your specify heitht and width

Comment: There no woocommerce folder in my wp-admin

Comment: i an mot taking about woocommerce folder, login in wp-admin and go to woocommerce menu in your admin section

Comment: Understood. I went to the settings and just as a trial I changed the three options to 500*500 but I still see the category thumbnail being cropped at 150*150.
Is there no other option perhaps. Because I am not talking about product thumbnail, but category thumbnail.

Comment: yes because old images is show still in old size, new image size will apply only when u upload any new product images.

Comment: and you need to install https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/ for already uploaded images.

Comment: I have this plugin yes. I noticed the change but only on the products thumbnails, not on the category thumbnails